# VBscript - wscript.echo perfect in Windows 7 - does not work in Window 2012

Tags: vbscript

I've created the following vbs script to show my problem

```
    Wscript.echo "My very first script."
    Dim price, vat, net

    vat = 16.0
    net = 100.0
    price = net * (1.0 + vat/100.0)

    WScript.Echo "Price: ", price, "US $ Tax: ", vat, "% ", price - net, " US $"
```

When I run this on my laptop (Windows 7 Professional) everything is beautiful
It displays the first echo message - I click on OK
It then displays the second echo message - again I get to click OK and the script ends

I then upload it to our server (Windows Server 2012 Standard) and

It displays the first Wscript.echo for about 2 seconds then ends.
If I comment out the first message it then displays the second message - again for a couple of seconds then ends.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Try replacing `Wscript.echo "My very first script."` and `WScript.Echo "Price: ", price, "US $ Tax: ", vat, "% ", price - net, " US $"` with `MsgBox("Price")`

Comment: The same thing happens but instead I get an error message - Too quick to read what it is.

Comment: Try doing this, `WScript.Echo "Price: " & price & "US $ Tax: " & vat & "% " & price - net & " US $"`

Comment: No change - It displays the first message for a few seconds then ends.

Comment: If I comment out the first message then it does the same on the second message

Comment: Hmmmmm, honestly I don't know what the problem is, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Timeout

> //T:nn      Time out in seconds:  Maximum time a script is permitted to run

is set to a low value. You can check this assumption by executing

```
WScript.Echo WScript.Timeout
```

See the section "Setting a Time-out Value for a Script" in [the docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156589.aspx).

You can change the (default) timeout via the command line interface (//T, //S):

```
cscript
Usage: CScript scriptname.extension [option...] [arguments...]

Options:
 //B         Batch mode: Suppresses script errors and prompts from displaying
 //D         Enable Active Debugging
 //E:engine  Use engine for executing script
 //H:CScript Changes the default script host to CScript.exe
 //H:WScript Changes the default script host to WScript.exe (default)
 //I         Interactive mode (default, opposite of //B)
 //Job:xxxx  Execute a WSF job
 //Logo      Display logo (default)
 //Nologo    Prevent logo display: No banner will be shown at execution time
 //S         Save current command line options for this user
 //T:nn      Time out in seconds:  Maximum time a script is permitted to run
 //X         Execute script in debugger
 //U         Use Unicode for redirected I/O from the console
```

and/or the "Script" properties of the .vbs file.

Before experimenting, however, you should talk to the admin of that server.

(BTW: Whatever you do, **don't** change your **correct** WScript.Echo lines to something [wrong](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) like `MsgBox("Price")`)

Comment: I'll review the rest of your comments and try to figure out how to change it.