# How to find out whether a webpage is opened or not using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I tried with this below code to find out whether the webpage is opened or not, but this code is not working for me. System is just flashing only the first opened webpage URL.

```
surl ="http://www.google.com/"
set shapp=createobject("shell.application")
For Each owin In shapp.Windows
  msgbox owin.document.location.href
  if Instr(1,owin.document.location.href,surl)>0 then
    msgbox "Window opened"
  end if
Next
set shapp=Nothing
```

The error message is:

> Script execution time was exceeded on script "D:\ie_open.vbs" Script execution was terminated

Comment: The code works for me (displays message boxes with the URLs of all IE tabs/windows and an additional message box "Window opened" for each URL containing the value of `surl`). Can you explain in more detail what you mean by "just flashing only the first opened webpage URL"?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  I have replaced the command owin.document.location.href with oWin.locationURL.  
When executing this script in command prompt, first tab URL in IE is flashed in message box and it automatically disappears. And system is showing the below message in command prompt:  

**Script execution time was exceeded on script "D:\ie_open.vbs"  
Script execution was terminated**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the error message "Script execution time was exceeded ...", the problem may be caused by a too small time out. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24069650/603855). Use something like:

```
cscript //T:0 "D:\ie_open.vbs"
```

to test this assumption.

A default timeout value can be stored in the registry in either of the following locations:

- `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings` (per user)
- `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings` (global)

Deleting the `Timeout` value removes the preset timeout.

Comment: with this command I am able to get all the opened webpage urls
    cscript //T:0 "D:\ie_open.vbs"

Comment: @user3751964 In that case check the subkey `Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings` under both HKCU and HKLM for a `Timeout` value.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers  I could see the Timeout value as 1 in HKCU and couldn't see the Timeout entry in HKLM

Comment: @user3751964 Delete that value under HKCU and your problem should disappear.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Deleted the value for Timeout under HKCU, Now I am able to get all the website names. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `owin.document.location.href` Use `oWin.locationURL`

Comment: Didn't make a difference when I tested it.